# How to aggregate data properly in SPSS

Tags: spss, aggregation

In SPSS I have a data in columns:

q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8

Q1 is a question 1, q2 is...
Each of the fields in those columns can take only one of following values (all labeled):
1 which is no 
2 which is sometimes
3 which is yes

In variable view it looks like this:
{1, no}
{2, sometimes}
{3, yes}

I would like to get information, how many yes/sometimes/no in total did I get, how could I do that? Thank you in advance for your help, much appreciated :)

Comment: Please read the [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help). Questions that are only about the nuts and bolts of data management are not on topic at this forum. Either ask them at Stackoverflow or one of the other [SPSS specific forums](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/807/1036).

Comment: Oh, sorry Andy, you're right. I will be way more careful next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this simply by using `VARSTOCASES`.  You can use the `Restructure` wizard under `Data` or just syntax like this (be sure that your original dataset is saved first):

```
varstocases
/make allquestions from Q1 to Q8.
```

Then run `FREQUENCIES` on the new variable `allquestions`.

Answer (score 2):

@Mateusz Chrzaszcz: first and foremost, try to get into the habit of working from [syntax](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-syntax-six-reasons-you-should-use-it/).

It seems to me you're looking for `COUNT`. Do not confuse this with [AGGREGATE](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/aggregate/). The big difference is that `COUNT` counts **over columns** and `AGGREGATE` counts **over rows**.

Now try and copy-paste-run the following syntax without any data open:

```
*Create test data.

data list free/id.
begin data
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
end data.

do repeat q = q1 to q8.
compute q =  tru(rv.uni(1,4)).
end repeat.
exe.

value labels q1 to q8 1 'Yes'  2 'Sometimes' 3 'No'.

*Now check out the data. It should be pretty similar to what you have. 

*Next, we'll count how many times each respondent ("row") answered "Yes" on q1 to q8.

count no_yes = q1 to q8(1).

*Check frequency table with bar chart.

freq no_yes
/barchart freq.
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called a frequency table, which shows the frequency at which all (observed) values were observed.

To get it in SPSS, go in `Analyze > Descriptive Statistics > Frequencies`, then put your variable in the list called `Variable(s)`. Make sure that the option `Display frequency tables` is checked. There are also other statistics, options, and graphs (e.g. histogram of your data, with or without normal curve superimposed) that you can get from this window as well.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but it shows me tables with results for each question. I want them grouped like "Questions from 1 to 33: 147 yes, 89 no, 84 sometimes" in a one table and on a bar chart that's why I was thinking of accumulating data.

Comment: This answer should not be downvoted, as it is a reasonable answer given the initial question. Two simple solutions (besides those already posted) to show the totals are to either use multiple response sets or `CTABLES` to show the total counts across different Q's. Using Ruben's data, `MULT RESPONSE GROUPS=$Q (q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8 (1,3)) /FREQ=$Q.` would produce the requested stats.